# Click just ones

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have a `JTextPane` to display questions call Qus, I have 4 `JLabel`, A, B, C, D. And five questions on different pages. When you select the correct answer a,b,c,or d, 10 point is added to a `JLabel`call `Counter`.

But my problem is, it time u click a,b,c,d it keeps adding 10 again, again, and again. I just want it to add 10 once on each page, if answer is correct on next page, it should add another 10 not multiple 10 on a page or answer, that will be a cheat.

Here is the code

```
// To display the result
string preval = Counter.get text()+" ";
Counter.setText("0");

//Pls note Counter is to display result in the GUI
//Now the question method
Public void  init() {
    Call question==0;
}

//First Question
If(callquestion==1) {
    Qus.setText(" 1+1");
    A.setText("A) 2");
    B.setText("A) 8");
    C.setText("A) 9");
    D.setText("A) 10");
}

//Answer, let's assume the answer is A// note A, B, C, D are all JLables
Private void AmouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    If(callquestion==1 && D.isFocusable()) {
        Int d= Integer.parseInt(Counter.getText());
        Int e= 10;
        Int f=d+10;
        Counter.setText(f+" ");
    }
}
```

Please note this is just 1 question and answer. In my project I have 20 of this. I just want each button to add 10 once, and adding it on multiple clicks Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you give another example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're going for one question at a time, why not reuse the page?
:)

First, we create a Question class...

```
class Question{
    String question;
    String answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;
    int userAnswer;
    int correctAnswer;
    boolean scoredPoints;
    Question(String q, int correct, String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4){
        this.question = q;
        this.correctAnswer = correct;
        this.answer1 = a1;
        this.answer2 = a2;
        this.answer3 = a3;
        this.answer4 = a4;

    }
}
```

Then we can create the question...

```
Question q1 = new Question("1+1",1,"2","4","6","8");
//constructor is question, correct answer, ans 1, 2, 3, 4.
```

Then create a list of Questions...

```
ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
```

And add the Questions to the list...

```
questions.add(q1);
```

Then you do the same things you'd do to present the question, however, you'd reference questions.get(x) where x is the question number (minus one, since array index 0 is equal to object 1).

When a user presses a button, such as A, you call your actionlistener and invoke:

```
questions.get(x).scoredPoints = true; //prevents cheating
questions.get(x).userAnswer = buttonNumber; //sets user question answer
```

x in this case is the current question number.

This way you can have a continuous stream of questions, their answers will be recorded and checked, and they cannot "cheat".

Comment: I should probably add that this only defines the behavior of the questions/answers, it does not define the scoring. That can be done by simply looping through the questions and checking if each answer is equivalent to the correct answer, and if it is, adding 10 points.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what the problem is: The AmouseClicked method gets called whenever a mouseevent occures (mouse_pressed, mouse_down, mouse_release). So this should do the trick.

```
 If(callquestion==1 && D.isFocusable())
```

needs to be

```
 If(callquestion==1 && D.isFocusable() && evt.getModifiersEx()==MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)
```

Comment: Okay . I am building say Who want to be a millionaires app with 20 questions. When you get each answer a point of 10 is added, wen u go to the next question and gets the answer, another 10 is addes. But my code gives me 10 wen when mouse is clicked, and when you click the same button again with out going to the next question, another 10 is added. So I want 10 to be added once, no matter how a user clicked at that same button, until he goes to the next page to get the next questions for another 10 marks

Comment: Can you pls input the answer into my codes, it quite confusing.

Comment: Boschma I tried it but it didn't allow the button to be clicked anymore,  10 wasn't added at all

Comment: How did you add the amouseclicked to the labels? With other words: wherefrom does the amouseClicked gets called from?

Comment: A is a JLabel  I changed the variable name to a. So i created a mouse clicked event

Comment: @ Rene Boschma. My code works, but each time I click the A button, it adds another 10 on same page. I just want it to add 10. And wen u click again it will not add again. Until next page

Comment: @chopsticks maybe you could post some more code so I can see the bigger picture?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the points directly use a map (question, answer) to store in which question what answer the user gave:

```
// somewhere in your main programme
List<Integer> userAnswers;
List<Integer> correctAnswers;

...

// at programme startup initialise to #answers
userAnswers = Arrays.toList(new Integer[20]); // create list full of null
correctAnswers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    correctAnswers.add(0); // set all correct answers to #a (change this accordingly)

...

// when user answers question #q with answer #a
userAnswers.set(q, a); // set answer at #q to #a
Counter.setText(getScore() + " "); // update the counter every time the list changes!

...

// getScore counts up the awarded points for all questions
private int getScore() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int q = 0; q < correctAnswers.size(); ++q) {
        int expected = correctAnswers.get(q); // assume initialised
        Integer actual = userAnswers.get(q); // may be null
        if(actual != null && actual == expected)
            sum += 10; // or have a third list indicating how many points each question awards
    }
}
```

This has other advantages like you being able to tell the user in the end exactly which answers he got right and which ones he got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I believe this is a better solution for your problem:

What you do in your setup:

```
JLabel a = new JLabel()
a.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  
{  
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  
    {  
        aclicked();
    }  
});

JLabel b = new JLabel()
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  
{  
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  
    {  
        bclicked();
    }  
});
//do this for c and d as well
```

The methods aclicked and bclicked is where you check if the right answer is given, and if so, award the points.

Comment: This is a good direction, but it doesn't prevent them from pressing the button multiple times. :)

Comment: @Psychrom this should work (haven't tested it yet). Changing the mouseClicked method in mousePressed method will work for sure. Maybe I misunderstood the question, but what I understand is that a player clicks the button (once) and multiple times the score gets added.

Comment: If what you understood is true, then yes, your answer is correct. 

From what I understood, the problem is that they can press the button multiple times and the score is incremented multiple times. 

So clicking four times would give them forty points. 

In my case, your answer would still require a boolean/flag or the removal of the mouselistener to prevent multiple clicks.